# Which operating system should I choose for OpenStack?

Tags: linux, openstack

So, soon we will deploy some new developers infrastructure on `OpenStack` and I have not so much experience in that sphere. First of all which operating system should I use? Mostly I use CentOS maybe it's a good idea to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu's support of OpenStack is more established than Redhat/CentOS. The OpenStack Community releases are generally supported on Ubuntu first with Redhat support trailing a few days behind.  Either will work though.

OpenStack lists both on their [Known Packaged Distributions](http://wiki.openstack.org/ReleaseNotes/Folsom#Known_packaged_distributions).

Update: RedHat published a [FAQ on their OpenStack support](http://www.redhat.com/openstack/FAQ/).

Comment: One of the key reasons to go with Ubuntu is that they will support OpenStack Essex to whatever the I release is called. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with CentOS, go for it - Openstack supports it. CentOS is one of the more popular distros to run Openstack on too so resources should be quite good.

[Here are the install notes](http://wiki.openstack.org/InstallInstructions) from their Wiki for different distribution versions.